# How to change vhosts entry when document root is now a few folders further down

Tags: vhosts

Im using Ubuntu in a VM. I have a script that creates Drupal sites and sets the appropriate vhosts entry. Below is an example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName d7.dev
  ServerAlias *.d7.dev
  DocumentRoot /home/drupalpro/websites/d7.dev
  <Directory /home/drupalpro/websites/d7.dev>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName d7.dev
    ServerAlias *.d7.dev
    DocumentRoot /home/drupalpro/websites/d7.dev
    <Directory /home/drupalpro/websites/d7.dev>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
    </Directory>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Ive checked out a site to work on however the web root is now a few folders down. So instead of something like this:

/home/drupalpro/websites/d7.dev

Its now

/home/drupalpro/websites/d7.dev/folder1/site-root

What do I need to change from the original vhosts file? Is it DocumentRoot and Directory but not ServerName and ServerAlias?

Answer (score 0):

From experimentation this appears to be correct:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName d7.dev
  ServerAlias *.d7.dev
  DocumentRoot /home/drupalpro/websites/d7.dev/folder1/site-root
  <Directory /home/drupalpro/websites/d7.dev/folder1/site-root>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName d7.dev
    ServerAlias *.d7.dev
    DocumentRoot /home/drupalpro/websites/d7.dev/folder1/site-root
    <Directory /home/drupalpro/websites/d7.dev/folder1/site-root>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
    </Directory>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```